# Define a Resource Action That Doesn't Serialize the Object

Tags: angularjs

Given an API:

**GET** /photos

**Response:**

```
[
  { id: 1, url: "...", loved: true, saved: true },
  { id: 2, url: "...", loved: true, saved: true },
  ...
]
```

**POST** /photos/:id/love `{}`

**Response:**

```
{ id: 1, url: "...", loved: true, saved: true }
```

**POST** /photos/:id/save `{}`

**Response:**

```
{ id: 1, url: "...", loved: true, saved: true }
```

Is it possible to define a resource action that doesn't send up serialized versions of the object for simple actions like love and save?

Thus far I have a factory defining my `$resource` but calling `$love` or `$save` on any of the results from `query` sends the entire object (I want to send an empty JSON hash).

```
angular.module("app").factory("Photo", ['$resource', 
  function($resource) {
    return $resource("/photos/:id.json", {
      id: "@id",
    }, {
      "love": {
        data: {},
        parameters: {},
        method: "POST",
        url: "/photos/:id/love.json",
      },
      "save": {
        data: {},
        parameters: {},
        method: "POST",
        url: "/photos/:id/save.json",
      },
    });
  }
]);
```